# Unable to get or create MAPI namespace; caused by "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID ..." exception

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, .net-4.8

I'm new to C#, .NETFramework and VSTO. I'm attempting to access Outlook Items in my C# code by their `EntryID` and `StoreID` through `GetItemFromID(entryId, storeId)` method as below:

```
static public object GetObj(string entryId, string storeId)
{
    var app = new Outlook.Application();
    var ns = app.Session; // or app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    object x = ns.GetItemFromID(entryId, storeId);
    return x;
}
```

which is resulting in:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with
CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000ffff
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)).'
```

The stacktrace is:

```
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   <calls from my other code here, which I removed>
```

I was on this path because of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35855456/5028870) and found the same approach on other places on the internet. I also attempted to get past this problem by using `app.GetNamespace("MAPI")` and it didn't help either.

Another approach that I through about was to use the existing `Namespace` object, but I couldn't find any API or examples on how to `get` it.

Appreciate any advice!

Few other questions that I'd love to hear your input on:

- Is there a `GetOrCreate` like method for getting the `Namespace` object?
- I've multiple outlook profiles with one set as the default and no prompts to choose the profile at start up. Could this be a factor?

Comment: Why do you need to create a new Outlook `Application` from your VSTO add-in?

Comment: In VSTO add-ins you need to use the `Application` property of the add-in class. If it is not available for you you can use the `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application` sequence of calls to get the instance anywhere in the add-in code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on using the `Globals`, that's what I'm looking for! As the question clearly describes, I'm trying to get Outlook Items from StoreID and EntryID and I don't need to create a new Outlook `Application`. I simply took that approach as another SO answer indicated (and I'm new to C# and VSTO).

Comment: I'd suggest posting specific questions instead of relying on other posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
The simplest way to get the current `Application` is to use:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
```

(as Eugene suggested)

Another approach that I've found (which might not be the most efficient way in the current context is below)

The cause of the exception is that there can only be one `Outlook.Application` running. This VSTO plugin is for Outlook and as it's already running, and so `GetObj()` cannot create a new interop instance.

I stumbled on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1118822/5028870) SO answer while looking for `get`ing the current running instance.

```
Outlook.Application app = (Outlook.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices
.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
```

Comment: There are multiple reasons why you could have problems with such code.